# HERE MAPS, how to reuse the code from the examples provided for fleet telematics to get up and runing

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I built a solution using google maps for routing when I came to trafic restrictions on truck routing I discovered that there is no support for that on google maps, I´m now trying to find an alternative to google maps.
I´m very interessted in HERE MAPS and fleet telematics, is there a way to use the code you are providing in fleet telematics examples instead of reading the api documentation and write the code my self from the begining both to generate the request and to do the rest as extracting information from the resonse,  drawing the route, showing the trafic signs, warnings etc...
I registred a fremium account on HERE developer and can upgdare to the appropriate plan in case I need to.
The examples on https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3.1/fleet_telematics_api has a bunch of keys for authentication, but I have only the app_id & api_key and I don´t know how and where can I get the rest of the keys provided on the examples web page:

```
<script>
  var app_id = "xxx",
    app_code = "xxxx",
    app_id_cors = "xxxx",
    app_code_cors = "xxxx",
    app_id_jp = "xxxx",
    app_code_jp = "xxxxx",
    api_key = "xxxx",
    api_key_jp = "xxxx";
</script>
```

Question 2:
when a route is approved is there a way to send the navigation instructions to the users(drivers) mobile/gps unit to follow allong the route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example on the website is outdated, here's how you can make a call to fleet telematics API with API Key:

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=50.110890,8.688090&waypoint1=50.107030,8.682220&waypoint2=50.109632,8.685839&waypoint3=50.108591,8.683774&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&apiKey=API_KEY
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I found that answer and make it work for the caluculateroute, but not for the "var truckOverlayLayer = new H.map.layer.TileLayer(truckOverlayProvider)" to show and hide the truckOverlay, is there a way to call that with only apikey because it is requiring app_id and app_code?

Comment: This seems like a separate question unrelated to the one here. I suggest creating a new question with full description for this.

Comment: If you look at the code of the example at https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3.1/fleet_telematics_api the app_id and app_code is used in several places, the one I´m interessted in solving is the one with which shows and hides the truckOverlayProvider in other words showing an hiding Truck restrictions on the map like truck weight, truck hight signs.

Comment: The response to this is too long, again this should be a separate question. Please create a new Stackoverflow question and I'm happy to answer.

Comment: I created a seperate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131819/here-api-imagetileprovider-truckoverlayprovider-show-and-hide-truck-restrict)