# HERE-API - how to create an app_id, app_code and api_key

Tags: authentication, here-api

I'm trying to replicate the examples from the fleet telematics examples at (https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3.1/fleet_telematics_api) into my app, but the authentication need app_id and app_code, I have only an api_key.
I want to be able to create the truckOverlayProvider to show and hide the truck restrictions.
What do I need and how can I achieve that, is there any tutorial step by step for this subject?

Comment: Not sure if this is still needed but I posted extensive instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424544/here-api-these-credentials-do-not-authorize-access-some-requests/59928082#answer-74550899

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Freemium account at https://developer.here.com/ and you will find there in your dashboard your AppID and api_key.

Check this post:
https://developer.here.com/blog/announcing-two-new-authentication-types

Update: I am sharing also a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: app_id and api_key are available but not app_code.

Comment: I guess that you are confusing the credentials of the "Javascript" and "REST" APIs with the "HERE SDK for Android (Premium Edition)" or "HERE SDK for iOS (Premium Edition)". I've updated my answer with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for the example that you shared, here's how they are making the call for truck overlay:

```
var truckOverlayProvider = new H.map.provider.ImageTileProvider({
    label: "Tile Info Overlay",
    descr: "",
    min: 12,
    max: 20,
    getURL: function(col, row, level) {
        server_rr++;
        if (server_rr > 4) server_rr = 1;
        return ["https://",
            server_rr,
            ".base.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/truckonlytile/newest/normal.day/",
            level,
            "/",
            col,
            "/",
            row,
            "/256/png8",
            "?style=fleet",
            "&app_code=",
            app_code,
            "&app_id=",
            app_id
        ].join("");
    }
});
var truckOverlayLayer = new H.map.layer.TileLayer(truckOverlayProvider);
map.addLayer(truckOverlayLayer);
```

Looking more closely at the call:

```
https://1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/info?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.22.0&apikey=API_KEY&output=json
```

[Here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/truck-information.html)'s more resources on getting map tiles truck information overlay